# Rails Form not saving Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I asked a similar question yesterday, but now I have a little more info.

I'm creating a store that allow users to purchase greeting cards (Happy Birthday, Valentine's Day)

I have two models: `Card` and `Recipient`

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :recipient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipient

  def valid_name
    if @recipient && @recipient.name.nil?
      @card.errors.full_messages.push("Name can't be blank")
    end
  end

  validate :valid_name
  validates_associated :recipient
  validates :recipient, presence: true
  validates :note, length: { in: 1..200 }

class Recipient < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :card

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

**Card Controller**

```
def new
  @card = Card.new
  @card.build_recipient                                   
end

def create
  @card = Card.new(card_params)
  if @card.save
    flash[:notice] = "Your card was successfully added to your cart!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Something was wrong"
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

**Paramaters**

```
def card_params
  params.require(:card).permit(:note, :amount, :recipient_attributes:[:name, :email])
end
```

**Form for buying cards**

```
<%= form_for @card do |f| %>

  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <div class = "inner-form">

    <p>
      <div class = "heading">Card Details</br></div></br>
      <div class = "card">You can buy your cards here!</div></br>
      <small>To customize individual messages, add cards one at a time.</small></br>
    </p>

    <%= f.fields_for :recipient do |g| %>
      <strong>Name of Recipient:*</strong></br>
      <%= g.text_field :name %></br></br>
    <% end %>

    <strong>Note:</strong></br>
    <%= f.text_area :note %></br></br>

  </div>

<% end %>
```

When I fill out the form, I entered a note and then the name of the recipient. I was greeted with this message

```
This form contains 1 error
Recipient can't be blank
```

I then looked at my development logs and found the following

```
Processing by CardsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"DxoxP01IV4GZSf+lXoB9bFO6kuHn0
IxdSUyneoAo8FI=", "card"=>{"recipient"=>{"name"=>"John", "email"=>"", "firs
tname"=>"", "lastname"=>"", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "zipcode"=>""}, "delivery
_date"=>"", "message"=>"hi", "credit_card"=>{"card_number"=>"", "card_verificati
on"=>""}}, "style"=>"1", "amount"=>{"{:in=>1..20}"=>""}, "quantity"=>"1", "commi
t"=>"Add to Cart", "state"=>"1", "card_type"=>"1", "card_expires_on"=>"1"}
Unpermitted parameters: recipient, credit_card
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered cards/new.html.erb within layouts/application (24.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 176.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The name parameter `John` was passed in according to the log. But the recipient value is actually a `Hash` instead of a `String`.

It also says that `recipient` is an unpermitted parameter, even though I permitted it.

I don't want to validate `:recipient`, only the recipient name attribute.

I even tried creating custom validators like the one above and running it through callbacks.

Nothing I try seems to work though.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your code, you permitted

```
:recipient_attributes:[:name, :email]
```

But params contain

```
"recipient"=>{"name"=>"John", "email"=>"", "firstname"=>"", "lastname"=>"", "address"=>"", "city"=>"", "zipcode"=>""}
```

Probably you should try this first

```
params.require(:card).permit(:note, :amount, recipient: [:name, :email])
```

The second issue, that now you have colon before key, presenting array of params

The third, is that accept_nested_attributes works, when current model includes has_many or has_one relations. But you have belongs_to.
Try to swap this relation.

Doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Looks like this works. Thank you. But now I get `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in CardsController#create`

Comment: In that case, I should swap the order of the form right? And have it as a `form for @recipient` right? And also a `fields for :card`?

Comment: No, card has_one recipient.
Base object, that has nested fields, should has_one nested object.
So the form remains the same.

Comment: I thought it was the recipient that had a card. And a card belonged to a recipient. Was it the other way around? Perhaps `validates_associated` belongs in `:recipient`

Comment: Redesign your architecture. More fundamental model should nest related models